# Height of AVL tree with balance condition of 2

Tags: binary-trees, discrete-mathematics

The maximum height of an AVL tree with a balance condition of 1 is 1.44log(n). So the worst case height is O(logn). However, if the balance condition was hypothetically 2 (meaning that the allowed imbalance condition between two child nodes would be 2), how could I find the maximum height of such a tree. Would I need to solve some kind of recurrence relation or fibonacci sequence. Is there an easier way of figuring out the maximum height of a tree with a balance condition of 2 by using what we already know? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T_h$ denote the minimal number of nodes that a standard AVL tree of height $h$ could have.

If $h>0$, then there's the root and two subtrees. One of the subtrees must have height $h-1$. The other must have height at least $h-2$, otherwise it's not a valid AVL tree. So we have the recurrence:

$$T_h = T_{h-1} + T_{h-2} + 1$$

And we can throw in $T_0 = 0$ and $T_1 = 1$ for obvious reasons.

The easy way to solve the recurrence is to denote $F_h = T_h + 1$. Then:

$$\begin{align*}F_0 & = 1 \\ F_1 & = 2 \\ F_h & = F_{h-1} + F_{h-2}\end{align*}$$

That is, they're Fibonacci numbers with the sequence offset by 3.

Since:

$$F_h \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{h+3}$$

Inverting this, we get:

$$h \approx \frac{1}{\log \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)} \log \left( T_h \right) + 3$$

And that is where the 1.44 comes from.

So what you need is to solve the recurrence:

$$U_h = U_{h-1} + U_{h-3} + 1$$

with suitable initial conditions.

If you can't think of a clever way to do this, you can do it the not-clever-but-always-works way by observing that:

$$\begin{bmatrix} U_h \\ U_{h-1} \\ U_{h-2} \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} U_{h-1} \\ U_{h-2} \\ U_{h-3} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{bmatrix} U_{h+2} \\ U_{h+1} \\ U_{h} \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{h} \begin{bmatrix} U_{2} \\ U_{1} \\ U_{0} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Next, perform [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) on the matrix. Let:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Suppose you can find a matrix $Q$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ such that $M = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}$. Then:

$$M^h = Q \Lambda^h Q^{-1}$$

Taking the power of a diagonal matrix is trivial, and this should give you a closed form. You will then need to find an approximate inverse to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this **mathematically** as :

### **Defining Worst Case**

Now, in any `Binary Tree`, time complexity of `searching` is  $O(h)$ where $h$ is ***height*** of the `Binary Tree`.
Now, for worst case, we want to find ***Maximum Height.***

> In case of simple `Binary Search Tree` with no Balancing Factor
> Condition on Nodes, this maximum height can be $n$ or $n+1$ *(depending
> on convention whether height of single node tree will be 1 or 0)*
> where $n$ is number of nodes.

Thus, we can say that `given number of nodes, worst case is maximum height`.

Interestingly, we can also say that `given height of a tree, the worst case is minimum nodes`. As even for such minimum number of nodes, we might have to traverse down the tree of height $h$, which we also have to do for maximum number of nodes.

Thus, the intuition should be clear that **Given Height of Tree, the worst case is minimum number of nodes.**

### **Applying this Concept on GIVEN Tree**

1. Let us try to construct **Given Tree** of Height $H$ such that **number of nodes** in the tree is **minimum**.

> Here we will exploit the fact that Binary Tree is a Recursive Data
> Structure (A Binary Tree can be defined in terms of Binary Tree)

2. We will use the notation **$N_H$** to denote Minimum Number of Nodes in **Given Tree** of height $H$
3. We will create a **Root Node**
   [image: Root Node]
4. To **Left** (or Right) of Root, add a **subtree** of height `H-1` (exploiting Recursive Property). So that number of nodes in entire tree is minimum, the number of node in **Left** (or Right) **subtree** should also be minimum. Thus **$N_H$** is a function of **$N_{H-1}$**
5. Do we need to add anything to **Right** (or Left)?
   Yes! *Because there is restriction of Balancing Factor on Nodes.*
   We need to add subtree on **Right** (or Left). **What should be it's height?**

   **$H?$**

   > **No,** then height of entire tree will become $H+1$

   **$H-1?$**

   > **Permitted!** since Balancing Factor of Root will become $0$

   **$H-2?$**

   > **Permitted!** since Balancing Factor of Root will be $1$

   **$H-3?$**

   > **Permitted!** since Balancing Factor of Root will be $2$

   **$H-4?$**

   > **Not Permitted!** since Balancing Factor of Root will become $3$

   We want minimum number of nodes, so out of `H-1`, `H-2` and `H-3`, we will choose $H-3$. So that number of nodes in entire tree is minimum, the number of node in **Right** (or Left) **subtree** should also be minimum. Thus **$N_{H}$** is **also** a function of **$N_{H-3}$**
6. Thus, to construct **Given Tree** of Height $H$ such that **number of nodes** in the tree is **minimum**, we can have LEFT subtree as
   **Given Tree** of Height $H-1$ such that **number of nodes** is **minimum** and can have RIGHT subtree as **Given Tree** of Height $H-3$ such that **number of nodes** in it is also **minimum**, and can add one root node. Our tree will look like
   [image]

   Thus, we can form **Recurrence Relation** as

   $$N_{H} = N_{H-1} + N_{H-3}+ 1$$
   with **base condition** as
   $$N_{0} = 1$$
   $$N_{1} = 2$$
   $$N_{2} = 3$$

> To create BST of height 0, we need to add one node. Throughout the answer we will use this convention

7. Now, this **Recurrence Relation** is **Difficult** to Solve. But courtesy to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341827/963109), we can conclude that
   $$N_{H} \gt (\sqrt2)^H$$
8. Now, let $n$ be the number of nodes in the **Given Tree** Then,
   $$n \geq N_H$$
   $$n \geq  (\sqrt2)^H$$
   $$\log_{\sqrt2} n \geq  H$$
   $$H \leq  \log_{\sqrt2} n$$
   $$H \leq  2\log_{2} n$$

Therefore, $H=O(\log(n))$
Or $O(H) = O(\log(n))$

Thus, **Worst Case Time Complexity** for **Searching** in this Given Tree will be **$O(\log(n))$**

Hence, Proved Mathematically!